# An adjective for 'a concept that seems random and built on wishful thinking'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I'm looking for an adjective that I can put before the noun 'concept':

A concept that seems **random**, **wild** (wild in the sense of drawing on various ideas and mixing them together) and built on **wishful** thinking and can hardly be proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that it's a [*fanciful*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fanciful) concept.

> **fanciful**, *adj*.:
>
> **1** given to fancy, unrestrained imagination, or whim :  guided by fancy, imagination, or illusion rather than by reason, experience, or
>   fact
>
> **2a** marked by fancy and unrestrained imagination in conception, thought, or consideration :  not governed or ascertained by facts,
>   realities, and reason

Answer (score 1):

**whimsical** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/whimsical)

> 1. spontaneously fanciful or playful
> 2. given to whims; capricious
> 3. quaint, unusual, or fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

**Blue sky (thinking)**

> noun
>   creative ideas that are not limited by current thinking or beliefs

Blue-sky thinking: Collins https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/blue-sky-thinking

[Disney releases ‘Blue Sky’ concept art for Epcot’s new Future World](http://attractionsmagazine.com/disney-releases-blue-sky-concept-art-epcots-new-future-world/)

[Iveco's blue-sky concept imagines the future of trucking](https://newatlas.com/iveco-z-truck/45656/)

*Blue sky* still often enclosed in scare quotes when used as an adjective.